# Adding jquery validation to a file upload

Tags: jquery, validation

Could someone point me in the right direction on this?  I'm very new to this so I'm just not sure what's going on here.  It seems simple enough but for some reason isn't working.

I have a (Telerik) modal pop up window which contains a form with several input fields, most of which use html helpers for the input.  I have validation for those fields working.  The form also has a file upload.  This is what I want to validate.

Right now, I just want to validate that the user chose a file. If they submit the form without uploading a file, they should get a message to do so before the window will close.

Here's my input

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" /><br />
<label for="file1" id="file1Error">Please choose a file</label>
```

here's the jquery to initially hide the error message, check for the existence of a file, and display the error if there isn't one

```
$('#Submit')
  .click(function()
  {
   ('#file1Error').hide();
   var file = $('#file1').val();
   if (! file)
  {
  $('#file1Error').show();
  return;
  }
  });
```

I feel like the code isn't being reached o something.  I've tried putting it in several places:  inside the existing telerik script registrar on the page (where the javascript to load the modal window resides), in it's own script registrar, nesting it within the .open() in the load script.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction to figure this out?

EDIT:
Changing the scope of my requirement for the moment.
I just want to show the error message when the submit button is clicked.  (I can add the validation later).  So why doesn't this work:

```
    //initially hide the message--this works fine

 $(function()
   {
      $('#file1Error').hide();

 //display the message on submit click--this does not work
   $('#Submit').click(function()
   {
      $('#file1Error').show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#Submit').click(function()
  {
   ('#file1Error').hide();
   var file = $('#file1').val();
   if (file == "")
  {
  $('#file1Error').show();
  return false;
  }
return true; 
//or $('#frm1').submit();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test it **before** submit the form. Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think my problem is more basic than validation testing.  Did you happen to see my edit?

Answer (score 0):

Check the fourth line. 
$('#file1Error').hide();